# Why are we interested in tangent spaces of a group only at identity?

Tags: lie-algebras

I am reading again about Lie Algebra, and one main concept is that of the tangent space of a lie group. We consider it to be all the possible tangent vectors as a path crosses the identity element in the lie group... but why exactly the identity element? Why not consider tangent spaces at a generic point?

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059352/tangent-spaces-of-linear-lie-groups).

Comment: Yep that answers it @RollenS.D'Souza. Thanks!